# Gmail app on LG Optimus U doesn't get email anymore

Tags: gmail

I have an LG Optimus U from US Cellular and I use the stock Gmail app. A few days ago, it stopped receiving any new emails. When I click on refresh it doesn't do anything, just fails silently. Also, it shows that my account has 4 new emails but when I list the emails, I don't see any.

Has anyone had this problem, or can anyone recommend a better email app?

Comment: Have you recently changed passwords or opted for Google's 2-factor authentication?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache and/or data for the app?

Comment: Do you have Auto-Sync on for your accounts?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem before.  Sometimes the "unread" count goes up as well, but the emails never show in the Inbox.

The best thing to do to fix it is to go to `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications` and clear the data for Gmail and for Gmail Storage, then to try syncing your Gmail account again.  If this doesn't work I recommend clearing the data for **all** Google apps -- Gmail, Talk, Voice, Google Framework Services, etc. -- then rebooting and trying to sync your account again.

Answer (score 1):

My phone showed the same Gmail synching error after failing to install a new, relatively large application. Some applications worked, but others did not. The phone couldn't synch Gmail and also reported a stubborn and mysterious low memory warning that rebooting and clearing application caches multiple times didn't resolve.

I ultimately returned the phone to its normal state by uninstalling the most recent application from its listing in `Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications`. This uninstall likely removed extra files that were both taking up space and interfering with Gmail. (I assume this is just one problem a failed or crashed install can cause.)

Once the uninstall finished, my phone dropped its low memory warning and started synching properly again. I was then able to reinstall the uninstalled program successfully, without further memory or Gmail problems.