# Gmail has stopped syncing

Tags: gmail

How do I get my new email to update and notify me on my Android? On a regular computer I can see **all** my email. On my phone I will not see anything new; it's always just the same two email messages. I pressed the refresh button and it does nothing. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Might be related: is your phone telling you that you have low memory? Usually google sync stops working until you free up more space (this only applies if the low storage space notification is showing).

Comment: Here's what Bryan refers to: [Does the gmail app stop syncing once the “Low on space” message appears?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/16575). Other related questions can be found via [this search](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[gmail]+sync+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: It was and i tried to free up storage. although not understanding why i have low storage to begin with cdue to me only having this phone a week. it wont let me log out of my email either

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7098/gmail-app-on-lg-optimus-u-doesnt-get-email-anymore?rq=1

Comment: Have you followed [the usual steps for dealing with a troublesome app](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/app-x-isnt-working-correctly-how-can-i-fix-it)?

Comment: i have not had the phone very long so i have no idea what the normal steps are. i dont even know what i am doing with the phone half the time.

Comment: Did you follow the link to that question?

Comment: You can lead a horse to water....   (This site should have an scheduled job which deletes the accounts of people who pop up, ask a question and don't return in the next couple of weeks)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Gmail `settings`. Most probably you can go by pressing your menu button. Then select your email address, such as `xxxx@gmail.com`. Make sure, you have `notification` option ticked. Go below and you will see Gmail Sync option, make sure it is `ON`. Now try refreshing.